# Moving from sheaves over spaces to sheaves over sites

Tags: intuition, sheaf-theory, topos-theory, big-picture, grothendieck-topologies

The first example of a sheaf that I have consciously come across is the sheaf of continuous (real) functions on some topological space. The fact it is a sheaf is equivalent to the pasting lemma, which says more generally that given two topological spaces $X,Y$, the presheaf $\bar h_Y:\mathcal O (X)^\text{op}\longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ on the locale of opens of $X$ defined by $U\mapsto \mathsf{Hom}_{\mathsf{Top}}(U,Y)$ is a sheaf. As a functor over the locale of opens of $X$, it is not representable unless $Y$ is an open subset of $X$.

This fact lifts to (locally) ringed spaces and says the presheaf $U\mapsto \mathsf{Hom}_\mathsf{LRS}(U,Y)$ is also a sheaf. Again, it is not, in general representable because our domain category is "wrong".

According to the functor of points approach to algebraic geometry, representability is really a very important thing. It seems we would like to work in a world where these assignment are sheaves. This, from what I understand, is a reasonable source of motivation for Grothendieck topologies.

For topological spaces it's clear that every object in $\mathsf{Top}$ comes with a locale of opens, and it's equally clear that $C^0$ is a sheaf over every topological space. This suggests replacing the locale of opens by $\mathsf{Top}$ itself, and asking for the sheaf axiom (in terms of an equalizer diagram) for all covers of *every object*. This would in particular solve the representability issues above.

This seems like a big difference from the usual concrete picture, in which sheaf means 'sheaf over a fixed space'. I guess we could get an equivalent formulation of a sheaf over a single object of a site by merely asking for the sheaf axiom to hold on each of its covers. And yet I can't think of an example where we fix our category of interest $\mathsf C$ and find that an interesting presheaf is a sheaf only over some objects.

Why is this? Is it simply saying that sheaves over topological spaces are functorial in the base space by $f\mapsto f_\ast$, or am I missing the picture completely?

**Update:** Well, an example would be bounded continuous (real) functions. If $X$ is finite, we do get a sheaf. This only strengthens the question of why the theory of sheaves over sites is so global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is just to have sheaves be representable, there is an ideal site for this purpose: $\def\Sh{\mathrm{Sh}} \Sh(X)$ (the covers are the epimorphic families). This site has the nice property that $\Sh(X) \equiv \Sh(\Sh(X))$.

(I'm glossing over size issues)

There's another way to look at this example. Let $\def\LH{\mathbf{LH}} \LH  \subseteq \def\Top{\mathbf{Top}} \Top$ be the subcategory whose arrows are the local homeomorphisms. Then, the fact you can identify sheaves with étale spaces means that there is an equivalence of categories

$$ \Sh(\LH / X) \equiv \Sh(X) \qquad \quad (\equiv \LH/X)$$

This particular example highlights the main trick I think you're missing; these kinds of "big sites" correspond to things over the *terminal object*. If you want to see how things look over some other object, you need to take the slice category.

While we can map topological spaces into $\Sh(X)$ by $Y \mapsto \hom(-, Y)$, this forgets a lot of their nature as topological spaces.  For example, the étale space corresponding to $C^0$ doesn't resemble $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}} \RR$ at all.

That is why we might consider a big site such as $\Top / X$; the category $\Sh(\Top/X)$ not only knows about sheaves on $X$, but it also knows about bundles over $X$, and even about correctly gluing bundles. For example, $C^0$ is the trivial line bundle $X \times \mathbb{R} \to X$, which really does look like the real line!